# ASP.NET vnext bin dll

Tags: asp.net-core

Normally, we put the dll in the bin folder and thats it
Now I put the interop dll within SQLite.Interop.dll on wwwroot/bin/

but still get this error
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

where should I put the interop dll on asp.net vnext?

Comment: whoever vote down the question, normally this should not happen within current asp.net. Now with the whole new project structure within vnext, without any official documentation or whatsoever. I have a library that trying to load another library, i tried to put it on bin folder within wwwroot, project folder, based on ApplicationBasePath, none of them working. For someone else who get this issue, heres a workaround, put it in this dir "C:\Users\{your username}\.kpm\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core\1.0.94.0\lib\net451"

Comment: Don't do it, above step will cause reference error within the project

Comment: Have you had any success getting SQLite to work in this scenario?

Comment: Hi, the above solution will work just once or (maybe) during publishing. The problem is, it will make issue with kruntime which i post at [link](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/990) but yes, I did successfully make the SQLite work by putting the interop dll on that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\Users\{change into your window username}\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7\bin

Works in asp.net vnext beta 7

Update 25-09-2015

After testing with another machine, that path is not always correct.
To be sure, check "path" environment variables.
On my case, the dnx runtime pointing to C:\Users\{change into your window username}\.dnx\bin

I put my sqlite3.dll over there and I can use sqlite on .net core :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a correct answer for you, but I do have one that works: put the dll in the Windows System32 directory.